# how to emulate Photoshop's "color" layer transparency with Image Magick?

Tags: php, imagemagick

So in Photoshop there's a transparency layer mode called "color", that retains brightness from the layer beneath, but takes hue / saturation from the current layer.

I need to change the color of some images dynamically with PHP, and I havent been able to fnd any info on what's the algorithm to do that, apart from the usual multiply / add / etc.

Comment: ImageMagick can not do everything photoshop can. one is free the other is not.

Comment: Obviously... but what I'm asking is not a liquify tool in PHP, I want a pixel blending operation which should be quite straightforward as shown by the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the algorithm is to transform both images from RGB to HSV, then copy the Hue channel to the base image.

ImageMagick has a [hue composite](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#hue) operator, which is [`imagick::COMPOSITE_HUE`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.constants.php#imagick.constants.composite-hue) in PHP. Based on a [comment here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php), this should work:

```
<?php

$img1 = new Imagick("image1.png");
$img2 = new Imagick("image2.png");

$img1->compositeImage($img2, imagick::COMPOSITE_HUE, 0, 0);

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $img1;

?>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean? You want to limit the effect to a certain area? If so, you can use a mask for the composite, can't see how to do it with PHP, but the [command-line tool allows it](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#mask)

Answer (score 1):

There is a library that can help you with your "photoshop" style requirement. It's called [pslayers](https://github.com/darrynten/pslayers).

You can use any mix modes you want, and stack as many layers as you like. It supports filtering too.